# Classification of referring sites and search sites in analytics

Tags: discussion, status-declined, site-analytics

I have just been given the site analytics privilege so I went to Stack Overflow's [analytics page](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources).  Over 94% of the traffic sources are from "Search" with almost all of that being Google.  So far, exactly what you would expect.

However, of the remaining traffic, about half is referrals and there is a pie chart that tells us which sites are making the referrals.  The two biggest referrers by miles are duckduckgo.com and bing.com, 39% and 31% respectively.  Both of these are actually search sites.

What are the criteria for classifying a visit as search or a referral?

Comment: Oddly, Bing also appears under *"Search Engines"*. Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics; presumably, this is some limitation of the source data from Google Analytics (DDG is mentioned specifically).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I must be blind.  I read that page and totally missed the remark about Duckduckgo!

Comment: Uh when was that privilege added?

Comment: Google analytics [has a long standing issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258390/why-is-duckduckgo-com-listed-as-referrer-rather-than-search-engine-on-analytics) with categorizing sites. This isn't something we are going to fix. It's documented, so it's a feature not a bug. ;-) (@rekire: Yesterday.)

Comment: @JonEricson - According to the answer here fixing it is trivial http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/265959/145673

Comment: @JonEricson - In addition to Martin's suggestion, it's also [quite trivial](http://jsfiddle.net/vs47dh84/1) to fix up the data while it's on its way to the charts API.  Why accept Google's "feature" when you can fix it?

Comment: Posted a separate bug report: [Analytics: DuckDuckGo is a search engine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307699/analytics-duckduckgo-is-a-search-engine)

Comment: @JonEricson: Unfortunately, it _hugely_ skews your statistics. You can't put a filter in place to simply recategorise duckduckgo before you render the stats?

Comment: Note: Google Analytics now includes DuckDuckGo in their [default-search-engine list](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795821?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article), so it's correctly listed as a search engine on the analytics page now.