# Analytics: DuckDuckGo is a search engine

Tags: bug, site-analytics

There is a suggestion already over in MSE but it's buried in [an answer to a related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/265959/169312) so I am posting it as a separate request.

As outlined in the linked answer above -- which in turn links to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795821?hl=en -- please **customize the search engine listing** for [Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources) <sub>(25k privilege to view)</sub> **in SO's Google account** to include DuckDuckGo as one of the search engines.

It would currently be the #5 search engine in referrals, with more than a million clicks in the last month, while the search engine listing continues down to some obscure Japanese (?) search engine which contributed 430 visits; and this month, there were 20 search engines which did not make it to the list at all (unsure if they did not register at all, or if the listing is capped at 20).  I'm certain something could be removed from the tail end of Google's search engine list to make room.

This isn't only about aesthetics; the usability of the referrers view is hampered by the fact that over 50% of the pie chart is DuckDuckGo -- it's hard to make out the smaller players.

(While SO can't do anything about Google Analytics's default search engine choices, **the ability to customize this list is available and should be used**.)

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged as a feature request and not a bug?

Comment: I was hesitating, but decided to go for "bug" since it's clearly wrong, and the fix is documented and straightforward.

Comment: Looks like you need to clarify, in that five voters mistakenly believed this to be a dupe.

Comment: [The fix did specifically get mentioned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305496/classification-of-referring-sites-and-search-sites-in-analytics#comment244478_305496) by the dupe, yet it remains declined.  It appears that SE knows about it but chose not to implement it.

Comment: @PetahChristian The answer with the fix was added long after it was closed as [tag:status-bydesign] which is why I think it deserves to be re-evaluated.

Comment: It seems that the reasoning at the time was "what can we do?" but now that a solution has been pointed out, closing this with a shrug is no longer appropriate, or even tolerable.

Comment: @triplee The fix was specifically mentioned the same day that Jon [tag:status-declined] the dupe.

Comment: @PetahChristian I fear that Jon overlooked the implications of that particular answer.

Comment: Note: It shows up properly now, since Google Analytics now includes DuckDuckGo in their [default-search-engine list](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795821?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).