# No reputation for answers on questions with negative score

Tags: feature-request, reputation, se-quality-project

It seems from [this recent Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354125/help-set-qa-teamdag-product-development-priorities?cb=1) that many people think question quality is a problem.

What if Stack Overflow would give no reputation for answers on questions which have a negative score? This will immediately remove all incentive to answer these questions, which in turn will remove the incentive to ask them.

If people really want to answer the question and help the person, they can, but they just won't get reputation. (Maybe there can be an altruist badge for these people :-)

Comment: Why? If they are correct answers, then I don't see a reason not to get sweet reputation points

Comment: @AlonEitan because these questions shouldn't be asked in the first place. The asker needs to learn, do research, use google. The answerer should better use his time to answer good questions. And if people really want to help the users with bad questions, they can help them in any case.

Comment: Related: [Should Answer Reputation be Removed for Closed Questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324430/should-answer-reputation-be-removed-for-closed-questions)

Comment: so.. do we do away with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal)?

Comment: @Stijn I hadn't seen that post, although I have noticed that these questions don't seem to be closed anymore. Maybe there are just too many of them for the community to deal with at this point?

Comment: @suraj That idea has been discussed before, unfortunately it was declined: [Get rid of the Reversal badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277576/get-rid-of-the-reversal-badge)

Comment: @ykay Don't worry, I think this idea deserves its own post. I was just linking to a related discussion to point out its existence.

Comment: So I can open a question with zero score and make all the answerers, who provided potentially valid and good posts, lose all their rep just by downvoting the question? Hmmm

Comment: @DavidG Why would people do that? In any case the answerers can upvote the question so it will take a few people to make it negative or positive. Hopefully they'll make the right decision.

Comment: You are also incentivising people to upvote bad questions so they can post an answer and get rep.

Comment: @ykay how would that work then?  Supposed I quickly answer a bad question before it was downvoted, and managed to get a few upvotes on my answer.  Then the question was downvoted significantly.  I would keep the rep from answering a bad question?  Supposed I answer a downvoted question but the downvotes were due to missing information that was later added and turns it into a good question.  My answer gets a lot of upvotes while the question still has a negative score.  The question eventually gets back to a positive score.  Do i get the lost rep back?

Comment: @DavidG I would argue that they already have that incentive...

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes I would award rep only to answers on questions with a positive score. We need to trust the overall community to upvote or downvote the question appropriately.

Comment: @ykay there are way too many holes in that.  A bad question that gets fixed (regardless of when an answer is posted) takes too long to get back to the positive size.  You are punishing someone for improving their question (by reducing the incentive to answer).  Which will cause them to simply reask the revised question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 maybe that will have the benefit of encouraging good questions?

Answer (score 6):

In a word...

## NO

We've discussed this before on a different topic. [Clean-up by downvoting? A ridiculous user experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307009/clean-up-by-downvoting-a-ridiculous-user-experience)

The TL;DR of that is this

> But blindly downvoting answers to avoid... retagging? Triggering automatic deletion?

This would invite a return of that problem. Essentially downvotes would become far more of a heckler's veto than it is now (where it only costs you rep). In fact, it would turn Q&A absolutely *toxic*, as nobody would answer negative questions anymore.

There are some edge cases where a user posts a bad question but gets a stellar answer. In these cases it would be detrimental to remove reputation. Sometimes a bad question does deserve a good answer. For everything else there's closure and deletion.

Comment: I don't really see the link between this question and the one you linked to. The only similarity is the word 'downvoting'.

Comment: In theory, closure and deletion would be enough to handle this problem, but it isn't, I'm sure you know that. A bad question can gather answers more quickly than it can get closed/deleted.

Comment: @Stijn Downvoting should not be used as a weapon or a tool. Downvoting should be done on the merits of the question. If we allow downvotes to be a determiner of upvote points on answers, it's inevitable it will be weaponized

Comment: `as nobody would answer negative questions anymore` That's *the goal* of the proposal, not a negative side effect.  There are negative side effects of the proposal, quite a few, but that's not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

First, while it's a piddly amount, [you can get a headstart on this by giving back the 25 rep you've earned from this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37158486/1079354)

Second, if I've said this once I've said it a hundred times by now:  **the mob can get it wrong.**  Just because a question is downvoted doesn't *always* mean that the question is bad.  I realize and respect that this is the held convention, but again, because people can vote on their feelings rather than logic, it becomes problematic when [decent questions get obliterated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354383/1079354).

Third, you haven't worked out the mechanics for this.  At any point in time if a question dips negative, would that mean that hundreds or *thousands* of reputation gets calved from an account?  Using Mystical's [venerable example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/1079354), if this question were to mysteriously be downvoted below zero, how much rep would be lost from each answerer?  It scares me to think that potentially thousands of reputation could disappear in an instant.

Lastly, this kind of thing projects an opinion of quality unto others, something [I've made noise about before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314117/1079354), which isn't really a good side-effect.  You should vote for a question based on its merits, and answer a question if it's on-topic based on its merits, not based on what a group of people think of it at any given time.  The mob can be fickle at times.

Comment: Your answer really saddens me. It's not about me. It's about the community. But I'm not really sure it's worth contributing to this community...

Comment: @ykay:  I admit that the 25 rep was more tongue-in-cheek and half-joking, really, although if you're suggesting that we shouldn't be getting rep for negatively-scored answers, then that'd be an ideal place to start.  My points about thinking this through and working out the mechanics still stand though.  You haven't stated what would happen to rep if a high-scoring answer is attached to a question which *just* dips negative at some point in time.  If you're not prepared to defend your proposal with some (what I'd consider) rudimentary use cases, then it's best that it falls to the wayside.

Comment: And you know what's even sadder someone actually went and down voted two of my questions...

Comment: That has nothing to do with anything...

Answer (score 0):

[Most SO traffic comes from search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305496/classification-of-referring-sites-and-search-sites-in-analytics). This means that most opportunities for upvoting happen when a user is actively searching for a solution to a specific question.

This results in upvotes being (roughly) correlated with how many people the answer helped. If an answer to a bad question helps a lot of people (thereby receiving many upvotes) I see no reason reputation should be withheld from the answerer. After all, we're maximizing for visitors helped, not askers helped.

If the question can't be answered well, that is, in a way that helps many future visitors (which, in my book, is a big part of what makes a bad question bad), then the answer won't generally get many upvotes, meaning there will be little reputation to remove in the first place.

I believe the potential of this proposal to prevent broadly-useful answers from getting rewarded outweighs its potential benefit.

Comment: There are *lots* of bad questions that get bad answers and get upvotes immediately after being asked by people that consider someone feeding a help vampire to be a good answer, simply because it's not technically incorrect.  Many of these answers never go on to attract upvotes from people searching for that problem.

Comment: @Servy That's my point. These answers get *a few* upvotes. Do you believe preventing people from getting reputation for a few upvotes for giving a not-technically-incorrect answer is worth completely preventing people from getting many upvotes for a highly-valuable answer? I don't think so.

Comment: The *vast* majority of answers to bad questions are bad answers.  Sure, there are very rare instances of very good answers to bad questions, but they don't happen often.  The vast majority of votes on bad questions are for bad answers, not good answers.  And of course if the answer to the bad question really is *that* good, then this would make it worth their while to either fix the question, or post the answer on a better question, both of which would be *desirable* behaviors.

Comment: Also note that, due to the existence of the rep cap, those very rare good answers that get tons of votes earn *way* less rep than the tons and tons of bad answers earning a handful of votes each.